# React の datepicker で月の選択画面で数字表記にするには？

Tags: reactjs

[React-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)を使用して年月のみのカレンダーを実装中です。
月の部分が1月ならJan、2月ならFebというように表示されてしまっているのですが、月の部分を英語ではなく数字表記にしたいです。
どなたか方法をご存知でしたら教えていただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同じ質問が次にありました。

- [Change locale in react-datepicker - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399915/4506703)

これに従って実装すると次のようになるかと思います:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import ja from "date-fns/locale/ja"; // register it with the name you want

registerLocale("ja", ja);

const App = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      locale="ja"
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      dateFormat="yyyy/MM"
      showMonthYearPicker
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

[コードサンプル](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-hft4jf?file=/App.js)